# VBA Click Through Website Menu

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I want to create some VBA to extract information from a website. I found the information in the HTML, but I believe it's only shown/populated in the HTML source when certain buttons are clicked on the page. I've been trying to use getElementsByTagName to perform the clicks but it has not worked so far. My code so far is to try for the second click straight away:

```
Sub googlesearch()
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    WebSite = "MyLink"

    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate WebSite
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each e In elems

        If (e.getAttribute("id") = "show-history") Then
            e.Click
            Exit For
        End If

    Next e

End With

 Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

I get Run Time error 438, the object doesn't support property or method.

The code for the element I want to click first is:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-trigger other-actions-btn" id="otherActionsButton" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" data-qa="toggle-other-actions" olive-menu-initialized="true" olive-menu-trigger="otherActionsMenu" olive-menu-position="below right" olive-menu="otherActionsMenu">Other Actions</button>
```

The code for the second button is:

```
<button class="item button-link" type="button" data-qa="show-history" data-action="show:history">View History</button>
```

There seems to be a lag sometimes between the page loading and all the elements being clickable because of something happening in the background, I'm not sure if this would be causing an issue?

Any thoughts welcome!

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the method you are trying to use is not part of IE but of `.document` so you would have needed `.document.getElementsByTagName("button")`

I would use the following:

The first button has an id so you could have tried:

```
.document.getElementById("otherActionsButton").Click
```

The second button you can use an attribute=value  CSS selector to target the `data-qa` attribute by its value:

```
[data-qa='show-history']
```

You apply as follows:

```
.document.querySelector("[data-qa='show-history']").Click
```

Comment: Thanks so much, QHarr! Was not expecting an answer on this but meant I could pick this up again :)